# Rails nested form, reject if blank, delete record on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested form "Letter", associated with a "Message" that is associated with a "Button".

Here is my Letter model:

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
  validates :campaign_name, :presence => true

  belongs_to :core_bot
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :letter
  has_many :filters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_deliveries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_reads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_sends, dependent: :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :filters, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

My Message model:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  validates :content, :presence => true

  belongs_to :letter, optional: true
  has_many :buttons, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :buttons, :reject_if => Proc.new { |att| att[:button_text].blank? && att[:button_url].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I don't want to save a button entry if "button_text" and "button_url" are blank. However, on edit, if a button was created and the user wants to remove it ("button_text" and "button_url" blank), I would like to be able to remove the record.

How can I do that? I thought about doing an after_action method, but maybe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: When the button_text and button_url fields are not blank on create. Then, the button fields on edit will be filled.

Comment: Adding a delete button? I'm not sure how this works.

Comment: Yes! But also, if the user removes what he entered on create for the buttons fields (he makes the fields blank), the button entry is not updated as it is rejected by my model :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow blank entries on edit only, add a validation to your `Button` model with the specified action: 
 `:allow_blank => true, on: :edit`   for both `button_text` and `button_url` attributes

Also, remove the `:reject_if` statement from your `Message` model and validate the presence of all attributes `on: :create` on your `Button` as well. This way the validations won't interfere with each other.

Comment: I added `validates :button_url, :presence => true, :allow_blank => true, on: :edit` in my button model but it still does not update the entry with blank values. I think the reject_if in my Message model is called before?

Comment: Remove the reject if and also add a regular validations to your button model that validates presence on create without the allow blank. This way edit and create have different behavior.

Comment: Updated my comment also

Answer (score 1):

To allow `update` with empty attributes you might want to consider moving your validations to your `Button` model like so:

```
validates_presence_of :button_url, on: :create
```

To delete the recrod simply allow the user to delete the record on "edit" by adding a link to your `delete` action, like so:

```
# edit.html.erb
<%= link_to "Delete", button_path(@button), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!